# Show that $[a,b] = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (a-1/n, b+1/n).$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Show that $[a,b] = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (a-1/n, b+1/n).$

Attempt: $a> a -1/n$ and $b < b+1/n$. This implies $[a,b] \subset (a-1/n, b+1/n)$. This implies $[a,b] \subset \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (a-1/n, b+1/n) $.

> Show that $(a,b) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} [a+1/n, b-1/n].$

Attempt: Similarly, $a< a+1/n$ and $b> b-1/n$. Therefore, $[a+1/n, b-1/n] \subset (a,b)$. This implies $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} [a+1/n, b-1/n] \subset (a,b)$.

Is this correct? and could you give some hint for how to proceed the other side?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have only proved the containments in the easier directions: you need $[a,b]\supseteq\bigcap(a-1/n,b+1/n)$ etc. To prove this, take $x>b$ or $x<a$ and prove there is $n$ with $x\notin(a-1/n,b+1/n)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fine so far. For added correctness I would add "for any $n$" somewhere appropriate in both cases. For instance right before or right after the inequalities.

For the top one, I would continue by considering an $x\notin [a,b]$ and show that it is not in the intersection (i.e. that at least one of the sets you're intersecting doesn't contain $x$). For the bottom one I would continue by considering a $y\in(a,b)$ and show that it is in the union (i.e. that at least one of the sets you're unioning contains $y$). The Archimedean property will be of use in both cases.

Comment: For the second one, let $y \in (a,b)$. By Archiemedean property, $\exists n$ such that $a+1/n<y$ and $b-1/n > y$. Then, $y \in (a+1/n, b-1/n)$. Could give some more hint to proceed from here?

Comment: @SihyunKim Since $y \in (a+1/n, b-1/n)$, we also have $y \in [a+1/n, b-1/n]$, which is a set in the union. By definition of union, $y$ is contained in the whole union. This finishes the proof of $(a,b) \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} [a+1/n, b-1/n]$.

Comment: Thanks. I am wondering, for the first one, if we let $x \not\in [a,b]$, then how can we use the Arcimedean property as we did for the second proof?

Comment: @SihyunKim In that case, we need to split into cases: Either we have $x<a$, or we have $x>b$. If $x<a$, by the Archimedian property, there exists an $n$ such that ... On the other hand, if $x>b$, ... Either way there exists an $n$ such that $x\notin \ldots$, and therefore by definition of intersection ...

Comment: I got it.  Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that might help you.  I would try to avoid proving both directions separately, and treat this as a simplification problem, simplifying the right hand side to the left hand side.$%
\require{begingroup}
\begingroup
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
%$

For example, for the second problem, which $\;x\;$ are in the RHS set?  We calculate, for any $\;x\;$,
$$\calc
    x \in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} [a+1/n, b-1/n].
\op\equiv\hint{definition of $\;\bigcup\;$}
    \langle \exists n : n \ge 1 : a+1/n \le x \le b-1/n \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{arithmetic -- the only real moment of inspiration}
    \langle \exists n : n \ge 1 : a+1/n \le x \le b-1/n \;\land\; a<x<b \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{...a simple calculation to isolate $\;n\;$...}
    \langle \exists n : n \ge 1 : n \ge \ldots \land n \ge \ldots \rangle \;\land\; a<x<b
\op\equiv\hint{choose a large enough $\;n\;$}
    a<x<b
\op\equiv\hint{definition of open interval}
    x \in (a,b)
\endcalc$$

That proves the second statement.

$%
\endgroup
%$